# How to increase disk space in linux

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, virtualbox, lvm

I searched but can’t find a simple solution and easy to implement.

I have a VM with two disks, one with **50Gb** and other with **20Gb**, and I need to increase 10Gb in the disk of **50GB** so that you have **60Gb**.

I use VirtualBox and I will do this on a machine with Oracle Linux.

I have created a new disk and added to the VM, however, needed to increase the space.

I know it is not an easy task, but if you can guide me it was perfect because I'm a newbie in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

1. ensure your new disk is present in your system (maybe you have to rescan your scsi bus with `echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan`)
2. create a partition with `fdisk` within your new disk.
3. Create a new filesystem with `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdx1`
4. create a new pv with `pvcreate /dev/sdx1`
5. extend your VG with `vgextend`
6. extend your LV with `lvextend`
7. resize your filesystem with `resize2fs`

Comment: It is not possible to provide all the commands? Thanks

Comment: All needed commands are there only the options (depends on your system) are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I know of

1. Inside virtual box change the space to 60Gb
2. Download the [gparted iso image](http://gparted.org/download.php) and boot to it.
3. Adjust the sliders and apply

Comment: And how can i change the space to 60Gb?